# Nodejs/Socket.emit not working, data not found

Tags: node.js, socket.io, beacon

So I'm currently getting uuid and rssi from Beacon and send it to the server using **socket.io**

Actually I get the necessary data : when I test in client side it show **1:undefined(ed6cfa91cbf1) RSSI-50**

but when I test in the server side, I get : { mac: undefined, rssi: undefined }

I can not find what's wrong in my code so I hope you guys can help me.

Client Side :

```
socket.on('connect', function(device){

var noble = require('noble');
var knownDevices = [];

function discovered (peripheral) {

    var device = {
        name: peripheral.advertisement.localName,
        uuid: peripheral.uuid,
        rssi: peripheral.rssi
    };
    knownDevices.push(device);

    console.log(`${knownDevices.length}:${device.name}(${device.uuid})RSSI${device.rssi}`); 

 //working, it show uuid and rssi

    socket.emit(device.uuid ,device.rssi ); //don't working
    }
```

Server Side :

```
   var scanner = io.of('/scanner')

   scanner.on('connection', function(device) {

    let payload = {
        mac: device.uuid,
        rssi: device.rssi
    }
    console.log(payload);

    connection.query("INSERT INTO DataTable values ?", payload,   function(err, rows) {

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on which port your server is running and on which port you have established socket connection in front-end??

In short make sure your server's port number and front-end connection